# Get first 3 words of a phrase

Tags: javascript, cypress

Can someone advise how i can check that a table row has a specific text.
i tried to do it with a command as such:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('start', (text) => {
   cy.contains('td',text)
})
```

Then i do cy.start('Specify a selector') in my test

My scenario is i am searching a table using first 3 words of a phrase..It has to be first 3 and if not found it should fail.
if it has the first two text correct it should not find it..It has to be verified by the first 3 text itself.
Assuming that i have the text

*Specify a selector to filter DOM elements containing the text*

in my test i am writing:

cy.start('td','Specify a selector')
i see the test passing but if i put "elements" it also passes

How can i achieve this please.

Thank you

Comment: There were so many comments..how did it get erased?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex instead of a simple string, and that should accomplish what you'd like. The `^` symbol signifies that this should be the beginning of the matched string.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('start', (text) => {
   cy.contains('td', RegExp(`^${text}`))
})
```